# Play Store just reported Unsafe Cryptographic Encryption (org.a.a.b.a)

Tags: android-security

We have just started to receive the following alert in the Play Store for a couple of apps that we publish.

Security alert
Your app contains unsafe cryptographic encryption patterns. Please see this Google Help Centre article for details.

Vulnerable classes:org.a.a.b.a

Affects APK version xxx.

Firstly we do not use any direct encryption libraries. Secondly there is NO library in org.a.a.b.a nor nothing in org.a____.a____ ie: nothing that starts with 'a' twice. We have recently installed a Firebase messaging component but again there is no library or import in the codebase that looks like it or includes anything with that library pattern.

What are we missing? These apps have been around for a few years and we are just seeing this now. Is there a plugin we can run in Studio or something (tried QABugs - full check for security errors but it reports NO errors)?

Comment: Did you find aby solution

Comment: No but on 4 out of 5 apps the alert/warning just went away about 2 weeks later without releasing a new build or anything - seems a little flaky...